# ApplescriptObjC method with a parameter

Tags: swift, applescript-objc

When I try to pass a parameter from Swift into an AppleScriptObjC method I get an error in the console saying

> unrecognized selector sent to object

I'm not very knowledgeable when it comes to using a Swift-AppleScriptObjC bridge, but I'm using the method set out [here](https://github.com/hhas/Swift-AppleScriptObjC).

I can get ApplescriptObjC to return an argument, but the function doesn't work if it has a parameter. So in the below examples, the method/function getPlaylists() works but when I try to call playPlaylist from say the AppDelegate I get the error message.

Applescript file:

```
    script iTunesBridge

    property parent : class "NSObject"

    to getPlaylists() -- () -> [NSString]
        tell application "Music"
        set theList to (name of playlists)
        return theList
        end tell
    end getPlaylists

    to playPlaylist:plist -- (NSString) -> ()
        tell application "Music"
            play playlist (plist as string)
        end tell
    end playPlaylist

    end script
```

Swift file:

```
import Cocoa

@objc(NSObject) protocol iTunesBridge {

    func getPlaylists() -> [NSString]
    func choosePlaylist(plist: NSString)

}
```

I think it's how I've structured playPlaylist in the AppleScript file but I've tried a number of different ways and all result in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, but have no idea how it works. If anyone could enlighten me I would really appreciate it!

I create two functions in ApplescriptObjC, one to get the playlist, one to set the playlist. In the bridge file, I set a variable that is `{ get set }` and then list the function to set the playlist. In my view controller (where I'm making the changes from) I create an objc dynamic variable which has a get/set. I can then change that variable and it triggers the AppleScript function to change my playlist... Code as such:

Applescript file:

```
script iTunesBridge

    property parent : class "NSObject"

    to playlist()
        tell application "Music"
           return name of current playlist
        end tell
    end playlist

    to setPlaylist:plist -- (NString) -> ()
        tell application "Music"
           play playlist (plist as string)
           reveal current track
        end tell
    end setPlaylist:

 end script
```

Bridge Swift file:

```
import Cocoa

@objc(NSObject) protocol iTunesBridge {

    var playlist: NSString { get set }
    func setPlaylist(plist: NSString)

}
```

ViewController:

```
class MainController: NSViewController {

    @objc dynamic var currentPlaylist: NSString! {
        get { return self.iTunesBridge.playlist }
        set(value) { self.iTunesBridge.playlist = value }
    }

}
```

As I say, I have little idea how and why it works and would really appreciate the answer. For instance, even though at no point in swift do I tie var playlist to the function setPlaylist, it knows to connect them. Set must be the magic word...